# Calling a web service that requires basic http authentication from wcf client

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have a wsdl from a web service, I generated the wcf proxy. No problem.

But I can not get my head around how to pass the user name and password. The webservice requires basic authentication - only username and password.

Any help ?

Answer (score 28):

Is Basic authentication configured in configuration file? Do you need to pass only credentials or do you also need secured transport (HTTPS)?

First you need to set up binding to support Basic authentication

Setup for HTTP binding:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicAuth">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Setup for HTTPS binding:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicAuthSecured">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Client endpoint has to use defined configuration like:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="..." 
            name="..." 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicAuth" 
            contract="..."  />
</client>
```

Then you have to pass credentials to the proxy:

```
proxy = new MyServiceClient();
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "...";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "...";
```

Answer (score 7):

For people (A) coming to this answer in context of .NET Core projects and (B) interested in changes in code, not in XML files:

1. Use [**dotnet-svcutil**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x) to scaffold code with WSDL.
2. Update **GetBindingForEndpoint** in **Reference.cs** method to enable [Basic Authentication in WCF client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication?redirectedfrom=MSDN#client).
3. Set login and password when using the client instance.

Example codes:

```cs
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
{
    if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.YourService))
    {
        System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
        result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
        result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        result.AllowCookies = true;

        // Set Basic Authentication with HTTP protocol (for HTTPS you need "Transport"):
        result.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

        return result;
    }
    throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
}
```

```cs
var client = new YourServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "yourservicelogin";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "yourservicepassword";
```

Comment: I've modified my GetBindingForEndpoint method as you showed here, added my ClientCredentials user name and password, checked request using fiddler and authentication is not part of my header. Any idea? I'm using HTTPS, so I set mode to Transport.

Comment: @Antonio, I think (but I am not sure), that there is no difference between http and https in the context of Basic Authentication. You have to look for reason why the header is not populated. Without your code - I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: By the way, have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication

Comment: I've checked it. Using OperationContextScope to inyect headers is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Refering to the answer of *@Gerard Jaryczewski* in **.NET Core** projects, you can also use the following extension method as editing the Reference.cs can be a challenge because after each update of the Reference.cs the changes will be overwritten.

```
public static class BasicAuthenticationExtension
{
    public static void SetBasicAuthentication<T>(this ClientBase<T> client, string userName, string password) where T : class
    {
        if (client == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
        if (client.Endpoint == null || client.Endpoint.Binding == null) throw new Exception("The specified client has no binding defined!");

        if (client.Endpoint.Binding is BasicHttpsBinding httpsBinding)
        {
            httpsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
            httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        }
        else if (client.Endpoint.Binding is BasicHttpBinding httpBinding)
        {
            httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The specified client has a binding defined which is not supporting HTTP basic authentication!");
        }

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
    }
}
```

**You can then just use it like this:**

```
var client = new MyServiceClient();
client.SetBasicAuthentication("myUserName", "myPassword");
```

Answer (score -1):

This should cover it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx
(See the Client section)

Comment: The question specifically asks about (HTTP) Basic Authentication. Your linked reference only demonstrates WSHttpBinding. WSHttpBinding uses username+password credentials in the SOAP envelope's header's auth block, which is not the same thing as (HTTP) Basic Authentication.

Answer (score -1):

I would say it is likely to depend on how the web service expects you to pass the information.
After all, you are only the consumer.

Having said that, it is common is web services to have the userid  and password passed in the SOAP Header.

You can refer to this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/authforwebservices.aspx) for a sample implementation of this scenario

Sample Soap Message

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AUTHHEADER xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <USERNAME>string</USERNAME>
      <PASSWORD>string</PASSWORD>
    </AUTHHEADER>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SENSITIVEDATA xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```