# Trouble connecting to API

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-security

*I am new to WCF/APIs and know little to nothing about security.  Let me know if I need to provide any more information.*

I am trying to connect to a service using

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService">
               <security mode="Transport" >
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
               </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentationService">
               <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
               </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="address1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService"
            contract="SoCalls.ISalesOrderService" />
        <endpoint address="address2"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentationService"
            contract="DocCalls.IDocumentationService" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentationService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

With this, I get this error:

```
'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException'

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. 
The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm'.
```

**Edit**
I followed the instructions suggested in the link provided in the comments, still is giving me this error.  I updated my code but I think I am still a bit confused on whether to use HTTP/HTTPS due to lack of knowledge of either service.

Here is how I instantiate my service:

```
private static SoCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient CreateSalesOrderServiceClient()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000 * 2;
        myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("address1");
        SoCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient client = new SoCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ("username");
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ("password");            
        return client;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a web service that requires basic http authentication from wcf client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495903/calling-a-web-service-that-requires-basic-http-authentication-from-wcf-client)

Comment: @CodeCaster by dublicate, do you mean trying to declare two <endpoints>?  I know the addresses are different, because they are two different Service References in my project.  Do you think the way I have them setup is confusing the program at run time? - thanks!

Comment: That comment means your question appears to be a duplicate of the question ["Calling a web service that requires basic http authentication from wcf client"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495903/calling-a-web-service-that-requires-basic-http-authentication-from-wcf-client), the latter being a link. Click it, implement the proposed solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster ah, sorry about that.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Show how you instantiate the client proxy and how you set the authentication info.

Comment: @CodeCaster I believe I added what you're looking for, thanks.

Comment: You need to change the security mode of the first binding to `TransportCredentialOnly` as well (assuming HTTP as opposed to HTTPS).

Comment: @CodeCaster That did give me some progress (I think?) a new error shows that reads: `The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.`

Comment: @CodeCaster I also went back to your link and tried both HTTP/HTTPS suggestions.  I just get my original error.

Comment: Do you have access to the service config file and assemblies?

Comment: @TomRedfern This is going to sound foolish, but my company actually didn't have access to the API for this specific database...we are purchasing the license.  The code is accurate..

Comment: Wow - facepalm moment! Glad you got it sorted...

Comment: @TomRedfern facepalm moment indeed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, I did not have access to the API with this specific database which is what was giving me my error.  I tried sending other credentials for a separate database from the same server and it worked perfectly fine.  Purchased the license required and the code works as expected.