# Azure Securing an WCF asmx with an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, wcf

Azure function calling an asmx WCF; methods work.

Adding security to the WCF (username, password) works from Postman.

I would like to enable the Basic Authentication on the Service.

How do you add on the Azure Function client contract to the WCF adding in the WCF username and password.

Either using a Certificate or simple username/password security.

(Side question; previos dev named the project "my app" with a space; what is the syntax in config file for name to use a space in the project name)

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64606237/1384539 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example for adding on the client: [Calling WCF client proxies in Azure Functions](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/04/17/calling-wcf-client-proxies-in-azure-functions/)

Also adding in the WCF username and password you can refer to:[How to Authenticate with a User Name and Password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-authenticate-with-a-user-name-and-password)

Thanks.

Comment: The linke "Calling WCF Client proxies in Azure Functions" describes the problem EXACTLY. However; in C# cannot use the #r syntax; error "#r is only allowed in scripts".

Comment: Link definitely identifies the precise problem; but not a solution in my situation

Comment: // Create a PortalServiceSoapClient
                    PortalServicesSoapClient portalServicesSoapClient = new PortalServicesSoapClient(new PortalServicesSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration(), url);

                    portalServicesSoapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUserName";
                    portalServicesSoapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";

Comment: I added user name and password to client; added the following to the service; which works from Postman; but in Azure Function, when calls the WCF Method the Soap Header is null

Comment: public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
        {
            public string UserName;
            public string Password;
        }

Comment: The situation is In the local environment the username and  password have been added correctly,but in Azure Function it does't work.You can check out the network and try again.If it still doesn't work,then upload a bug file to the Azure.